# Get OAuth2 access token or code using Freshplanet ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, oauth-2.0, ane

Struggling to find a way to get OAuth2 access token or code from Google. I am using Freshplanet's ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services.

I am saving user data to GameSparks cloud. GameSparks needs access token or code. It will get G+ user details with this token and link G+ account to current GameSparks user account. If user will change device or reset Android OS and log in with same Google account, the user will retrieve his/her saved data from GS.

Sadly, as I see, Freshplanet ANE has no method integrated in it to get access token .

I tried to add OAuth 2.0 Library for ActionScript to this ANE but this way user should be authenticated again after authenticating with ANE. SSO doesn't work with this library and user should enter their credentials. Dead end.
Link to library:
http://blogs.adobe.com/charles/2012/05/oauth-2-0-library-for-actionscript.html

Comment: I have no idea about Freshplanet ane, just a suggestion.Maybe, you can try to keep the access token and refresh token after your apps authenticated by Google and then pass it to the ane.

Comment: I would be glad to keep it if I could get it with FreshPlanet ANE. The ANE should get it and let me use it.